# Flutter - Give Index for dynamic http.post json response

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I already have a button to fetch the API with function to ++increment index and set the new parameter on **every click**. My question is, how to set 'like a cache' for json response as index?

here my http.post request =

```
  List<dynamic> _myResponse = [];

  Future<void> trytoFetch(myIndex, parameter) async {
    var url =
        "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/$parameter";
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    };
    final response = await http.post(url, headers: headers);
    final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      setState(() {
        _myResponse[myIndex] = responseJson; // ITS DOESNT WORKS
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {});
      throw Exception('Failed to load internet');
    }
  }
```

My goal is like

```
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      setState(() {
        _myResponse[0] = responseJson; // return responseJson from parameter
        // Then I click the button with new parameter value and increment index
        _myResponse[1] = responseJson; // return responseJson from new parameter
        // Then I click the button with another new parameter value and increment index
        _myResponse[2] = responseJson; // return responseJson from new parameter again
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {});
      throw Exception('Failed to load internet');
    }
```

and in the end, I can simply print the returned json

```
print(_myResponse[0]);
print(_myResponse[1]);
print(_myResponse[2]);
```

How to achieve this? is it possible? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of, you shouldn't pass index as a parameter to your method. 
`responseJson` variable is a Map, you should convert that map to the object you need.

I suggest taking a look at [this](https://medium.com/flutter/some-options-for-deserializing-json-with-flutter-7481325a4450).